# Linear PDE of degree 2: general form and an example

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> > As the general form of a linear PDE of degree 2 we wrote
> >     $$
> > (Lu)(x):=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}+c(x)u=f(x)
> > $$
> >     Now I have the PDE
> >     $$
> > (1+x^2)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-2x\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}-(1+u^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-u=1
> > $$

I try to transfer the general form to this example.

What I see is:

$$
a_{11}(x)=1+x^2,~~a_{12}(x)=-2x,~~c(x)=-1,~~f(x)=1
$$

But what are the other coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have $\partial u/\partial x$ multiplied by $\partial u/\partial y$, it is not linear.

Comment: I have to apply a maximum principle here to show that for the PDE above  and the condition $u(x,y)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+y^2}$ on the border it is for a nonnegative solution $u(x,y)\leq 1$. In our reading we had a maximum principle for linear elliptic PDE. So I thought it must be linear and elliptic... hm!

Comment: I'll ask a separate question for that.

Comment: This is a quasi-linear PDE, right?